# Putting space in between mat-panels within a mat-accordion?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use a mat-accordion to hold my mat panels. Accordion displays the mat-panels as all  on top of one another with no space in between.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-expansion-panel>

  <mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I would like there to be some space in between each panel, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there a way to make this happen in the CSS or HTML?

Comment: What css classes does the panel have?

Comment: I haven't put anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: When you inspect the rendered panel with dev tools, what CSS classes do you see?

Answer (score 0):

just

```
.mat-expansion-panel{
  margin-bottom:.25rem
}
```

tip: select tools in your navigator F2, see the elements and the class Angular write, try change the class in a css